# check box is not working to activate or deactivate sound in android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-checkbox, android-toast

lam new starter in android,in my simple game app,I used check box to activate or deactivate sound, but when l run the app in emulator and tic on the check box to deactivate is not working and the  music still on ,any help is appreciated

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.CheckBox;
   import android.widget.Toast;

    public class Setting extends Activity {
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.setting);

   }
public static MediaPlayer Sounds;

private CheckBox sound;
private Boolean isChecked = false;

public void Is_checked() {
    if (isChecked) {

        Sounds.start();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Sound is activated ",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    else {
        Sounds.stop();
        Sounds = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.preview);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Sound is deactivated ",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}}
```

XML CODE

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#CD853F" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/sound"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="78dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="86dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/soundt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/sound"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sound"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
    android:text="@string/text10_view"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 CheckBox sound = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.sound);
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                Sounds.start();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sound is activated ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Sounds.stop();
                Sounds = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.preview);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sound is deactivated ",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```